# Expected Fisher information from R's glm routine

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I am trying to better understand aspects/implications of the observed versus expected information in the context of maximum likelihood estimation. Part of this involves simulating data. If I generate outcome data from the following logistic model:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 5000
c1 <- rnorm(n,3,1.5)
c2 <- rnorm(n,5,1.75)
x <- rnorm(n,1+1.25*c1+1.75*c2,1.5)
p<-1/(1+exp(-(-13.5+log(1.5)*x+log(1.25)*c2+log(1.75)*c2)))
y <- rbinom(n,1,p)
dat<-data.frame(c1,c2,x,y)
```

Then then, if I understood correctly, this code gives me the observed information matrix:

```
a<-glm(y~x+c1+c2,data=dat,family=binomial(link="logit"))
solve(vcov(a))
```

But I can't figure out how to obtain the expected information matrix.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can't figure out how to obtain the expected information matrix.

Firstly, the observed information matrix and  the expected information matrix coincide in this case since you use a canonical link function (see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Fitting) and the reference).

> ..., if I understood correctly, this code gives me the observed information matrix

Secondly, `vcov` gives you [image: formula] (see `getS3method("vcov", "glm")` and `getS3method("summary", "glm")`) where psi is the dispersion parameter, X is the design matrix and W is the working weighs. AFAIR the IWLS method used by `glm` is equivalent to Fischer scoring also when a non-canonical link function is used. Consequently, this would be the expected information matrix and not the observed information matrix.

Comment: So how to you calculate the observed information matrix then from a GLM fit?

Comment: Call `vcov` or do as described here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/332097/81865